# Unremovable Links in OSX Finder Sidebar

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, finder, sidebar

Some links seem to be broken and can not be clicked. Drag & Drop to delete does also not work for any link in sidebar. Some can be removed by alt-click "remove from sidebar".

I had disk utility fix permissions, not helping.

How can I reset this mess or fix the link entries in the finder sidebar.

Clean install from Time Machine expected to work, but currently too time costly.

Comment: Are you only having trouble with the **Places** section or other parts, too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Command + click and drag the icons off the side bar.
2. Control + right click to get a context menu and select *Remove*.

This is new with Mac OS X 10.6.7.

Comment: This is a proper answer: Simply dragging out does no longer work, `Command` needs to be held down (only then the "cloud" symbol will show up).

Comment: yes... worked! thx.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting this file:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
```

and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

In Snow Leopard - there is no point restarting or resetting plists as its something Apple have actively changed as people were dragging items off by mistake!

Therefore if it is a folder you can right click and select remove from sidebar, or if it is a file you can command drag the item and it will dissapear in a puff of smoke as before!

Comment: last info (below) is wrong - deleting the .plist file solves the problem and Snow Leopard is neither preventing nor actively helping the user to 'not' do it.
Drag it off to Desktop, restart and sidebar is reset.